# Ajax.BeginForm OnFailure invoked when ModelState is InValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to call "OnFailure" when ModelState is not valid in controller.

In My LoginView

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Login",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "onError" }))
 {

 }
```

In Controller

```
[httpPost]
public ViewResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {

   }
   else
   { 
     ModelState.AddModelError("login is fail")
   }
   return View("Login",model)
}
```

so i want call onSuccess Method if ModelState is valid and if it fail then call only OnError method with display all error which are in Model State.

Comment: What do you do in the Success function? Do you redirect? From what I understand you want to display error messages in case validation fails => you want to return a partial view containing the logon form and then refresh the corresponding portion off your DOM. But what about the success case? What do you want to return to the client in this case? A View?

Comment: Thank Darin for replaying me yes i want to redirect in Success but in Failure i want call only OnFailure with error message. currently in application it call onSuccess method even ModelState is not valid

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's what you could do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // everything went fine and we want to redirect in this case =>
        // we pass the url we want to redirect to as a JSON object:
        return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("SomeController", "SomeAction") });
    }
    else
    { 
        // there was an error => add an error message
        ModelState.AddModelError("login is fail")
    }

    // return a partial view instead of a full vire
    return PartialView("Login",model)
}
```

and then all you need is the Success function:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "loginAjaxSuccess" }))
{

}
```

in which you could test in which case you are:

```
function loginAjaxSuccess(result) {
    if (result.redirectTo) {
        // the controller action returned a JSON result => it was a successful login
        // => we redirect the browser to this url
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    } else {
        // the action returned a partial view with the form containing the errors
        // => we need to update the DOM:
        $('#Login').html(result);
    }
}
```

By the way if you are using unobtrusive client side validation in the case of error where you are refreshing the form you will need to manually force the parsing of the new validation rules, otherwise next time you attempt to submit the form, client validation won't work:

```
} else {
    // the action returned a partial view with the form containing the errors
    // => we need to update the DOM
    $('#Login').html(result);

    // Now that the DOM is updated let's refresh the unobtrusive validation rules on the form:
    $('form').removeData('validator');
    $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
}
```

Comment: Drin when i use Viewresult it not allow me to use Json and also ViewResult can not return PartailView

Comment: Thanks Darin it's really useful

Answer (score 6):

When you detect the problem in the ModelState, set the StatusCode of the response object to something like 400 (You can get the code from the System.Net.HttpStatusCode class)

That will fire the onfailure method.

Si

Comment: This does not work on our test environment but works on my dev machine.  On test, returning 400 doesn't fire the onfailure method.  Any clues?