# Asp.Net MVC - Preventing OnSuccess callback to be triggered whitin Ajax.BeginForm due form validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, callback, ajax.beginform

Is there a way to prevent Ajax OnSucess callback function to be triggered in a condition?

I have this Ajax.BeginForm and OnSuccess I have some js code, but if the validation fails I don´t want the function to be called.

This is the code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "vall", OnSuccess = "closeDialog('RegistroUsuario')" }))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check in whether Model is valid or not in onSuccess function

OR you can call **OnFailure** method by

- setting StatusCode of the response object to something like 400.
- throw exception in Model invalid state it will call OnFailure method.

please refer following link

[Ajax.BeginForm OnFailure invoked when ModelState is InValid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599090/ajax-beginform-onfailure-invoked-when-modelstate-is-invalid)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found a way to fix a couple of errors in my code and now it is working flawless. I´ll keep that!! Tks